# Problem with audio while using headset

Tags: release-loki, audio

I'm using elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki 64 bit on my laptop. Now I can't hear sounds of my audio or any video file through my headset. Even though I plug them the sound will come out of the inbuilt speaker and interestingly the mic in the headset start working and will be ready to take the input. The change for output device on settings for sounds also shows nothing other than the built in audio device.

Are there any suggestions which would help me to use my headset normally while plugging into the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my imac 2008 with elementary, try updating first and restart since i believe there was a bug regarding the same:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo reboot
```

once it boots back check with earphone rather than hi res audio headphones like in my case audio-technica m50x didn't work although cheap earphones did.

Comment: NO....this dint worked for me... :-(....!! Are there any other method?..Or is that the problem of drivers??

Comment: could u try these`1> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
2> sudo apt-get update
3> sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)`

Comment: while running the second command you have mentioned I found a error like fetching failed from this URL - http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages . I hope my required package might be this one, am not sure either.

Comment: try  `alsactl restore` if that doesn't work either try https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working